# Iterate array and with index of element print another array. Handleblar - Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to iterate over an array in handlebar, and with the index of each element print one element in other json or array that i have defined.

something like this:

```
{{#each groups as |group index|}}
    {{#sticky-element top=41}}
       {{ad-component data=adGroup.[index].ad2 class="average-ad"}}
    {{/sticky-element}} 
{{/each}}
```

My component its something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  adGroup: {
    '0': {"ad1": "div-gpt-ad-123-0", "ad2": "div-gpt-ad-123-4"},
    '1': {"ad1": "div-gpt-ad-123-1", "ad2": "div-gpt-ad-123-5"},
    '2': {"ad1": "div-gpt-ad-123-2", "ad2": "div-gpt-ad-123-3"}
  }
});
```

but pitifully it is not possible do this in handlebar.

Some people recommend me use computed properties, but how can I create a computed property for this mission?

I don't know if these last 2 days are not my lucky days or what's going on, because i think this is something simple, but I cannot with this, some help please?

Comment: what is `groups`, why do you loop through it? do you even need `group`? Because, for this you can loop through `adGroup` directly with `each-in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you structure `adGroup` as and array and not an object

```
adGroup: [
  {"ad1": "div-gpt-ad-123-0", "ad2": "div-gpt-ad-123-4"},
  {"ad1": "div-gpt-ad-123-1", "ad2": "div-gpt-ad-123-5"},
  {"ad1": "div-gpt-ad-123-2", "ad2": "div-gpt-ad-123-3"}
]
```

You could use ember-composable-helpers

`ember install ember-composable-helpers`

and get the value like

```
{{#each groups as |group index|}}
  {{#sticky-element top=41}}
   {{ad-component data=(get (object-at index adGroup) 'ad1') class="small-ad"}}
  {{/sticky-element}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: If groups is adGroup, looping through the array could just be `data=group.ad1` the index wouldn't be necessary.